# How to get the detail of dailymotion video

Tags: android, dailymotion-api

I have list of dailymotion videos, i want when user click on any video the activity redirect to the next activity and show the video detail like number of viewers, comment count, duration, video name etc. Is the possible to get video detail, if yes then how to get it?

Comment: Thank you! I think you are asking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687995/how-to-get-access-token-for-get-particular-users-dailymotion-videos. As of now I have no direct answer but I'll try my best to get a solution for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help you https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-fields. This has a lot fields related to video which you need and more. You can find the usage [here](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#fields-selection)